# Jquery ajax request on focusout and enter

Tags: jquery, keypress, focusout

I want to request a ajax query when focus on input field is lost or when the user hits enter in the input field.

I have following code for doing so

```
function editVK() {
    var input = $('.check_vk');
    input.keydown(function () {
        // DO some markup
    }).focusout(function () {
        // execute ajax in function
        calculateVolleKist($(this));
        return false;
    }).on('keypress', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
           // execute ajax in function   
           calculateVolleKist($(this));
           return false;
        }
    });
}

function calculateVolleKist(elem) {
    var regel = elem.closest("tr");
    var article_id = regel.attr('data-article_id');
    var basket_id = regel.attr('data-basket_id');
    var vk = parseFloat(formatToDecimal(elem.val()));

    $.ajax({
        url: 'beltramibasket.php?action=wijzig_volle_kist&basket_id='+basket_id+'&article_id='+article_id+'&vk='+vk,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.basket_body').html("");
            $('.basket_body').html(data);
            editVK();
        }
    });
}
```

When using this code, my first change in the input fires 1 request. My second change fires 2 request, my 3 request fires 4 request and so on unit my browser chrashes.

**EDIT**
Included 2nd function. My response is HTML , I clear the body and put html back into the body. After that I execute the function editVK again. Because I want to trigger other request when editing the input box.

Comment: whats the issue you are facing

Comment: How many elements '.check_vk' do you use?

Comment: The code you posted here looks correct. The (quite common beginners-) problem you face is either that you somewhere register an Eventhandler inside another eventhandler (probably in `keydown`) which increases the amount of functions triggering potentially which each subsequent event. Alternatively, you have the class given to multiple elements and forgot to stop the event propagation.

Comment: When focussing out the input field or hitting enter in the input field. The function to fire the ajax request is execute multiple times. When hitting enter for the 3rd time in the input field, 4 ajax request are send. When I change my input field and hit enter again 6 request are send what makes my browser crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert this before your jQuery code:

```
input.unbind('keydown');
input.unbind('focusout');
input.unbind('keypress');
```

*not 100% sure if this is the source of your problem but it's possible that your are registering the events every time new.*

Comment: This solved the problem thank you. I don't know if my approche is correct or the 'best' to do. But now its working correctly.

Comment: @JoachimVanthuyne while this fixes the issue, it does not address the initial problem. Exchanging the whole body content is probably the wrong way to go. You could basically go for a normal http request in such a case...

Answer (score 0):

try with this code it is working fine for me

```
var input = $('.check_vk');
input.focusout(function () {
    // execute ajax in function
    calculateVolleKist($(this));
    return false;
}).keypress(function(event) { 
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
            //code to execute here
             calculateVolleKist($(this));
       return false;
        }
    }
});
```